# Controlling pivotItems in pivot in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivotviewer

i want to control that which pivotItem comes at first whenever my app starts?
code please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
myPivotControl.SelectedIndex = 5;
```

or, if the pivot item has a Name:

```
myPivotControl.SelectedItem = myPivotItem;
```

Comment: it does not SelectedIndex or SelectedItem. It have SelectedItemProperty and SelectedIndexProperty and it not taking the 5 or name of pivot item.

Comment: Make sure you use the NAME of the control. You are using the class name and thus see the static properties.

Comment: How to use SelectedIndex..?? how to set index for pivot items..??

Comment: It is just the order in which they have been added to the Pivot control

Comment: What should i do for "ArgumentException was Unhandled"...??

Comment: Please add the XAML and the C# code to your question so I can understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

OnNavigatedTo of the particular page, in your case default task page,(First page of you application), add the code code to selectItemIndex or SelectedItem.

use the following code , past in Page.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

PivotControl1.SelectedIndex = 5; 

}
```

It opens the page with the specified pivot item at the first.